# How can I redeploy my spring boot application on azure spring cloud using intelliJ plugin

Tags: spring-boot, azure, deployment, intellij-plugin, azure-spring-cloud

We are currently running our application on azure spring cloud.
Its a backend spring boot application with some controller API's exposed.

Now after running the first deploy on a newly created app in the azure spring cloud we are unable to redeploy a newer version. We're not using the staging area but rather direct build to default (production) stage.

To do these deploys we use Intellij Azure plugin for spring cloud.
Selecting option deploy: [image]

and run deploy:

[image]

next we see succesfull deploy on azure:

[image]

A new pod has been created and we see logs under a different id.

[image]

This would suggest that everything went okay. However when we now try our updated controller endpoint, the changes are not there. We never see the second debug messag "Test update" which was added.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/login")
public ResponseEntity<JwtResponse> loginUser(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
    logger.debug("login attempt " + loginRequest.toString());
    logger.debug("Test update");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Is this a bug or is there no option to redeploy an application and should you always create a new one?

To check if we were not missing build failures in new version we also created a new app and deployed the changes to this one. The debug message was printed.

Comment: It is working on terminal now using az spring cloud. This is how we noticed that the upload of new resource was stuck without returning error message.

Answer (score 0):

Redeploy should create new artifact and deploy all the changes to the existing Azure Spring App.

Our suggestions here:

1. Upgrade the Intellij Azure plugin to version v3.70.0
2. Before deploying to Azure Spring Apps, please check whether there is a new Artifact being generated.
   [Check Artifact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VmMa.png)

Reference doc:
[Deploy Spring Boot applications using IntelliJ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-apps/how-to-intellij-deploy-apps)